Polars: how worthwhile is it to pursue Enum over Categorical?
I can always recast a column which I initially made categorical, into a column which is an enum, once a DataFrame is "finalized".
But: is this worth it? Are there any benefits in terms of performance or memory usage (probably not)?

Enum data types don't require any synchronization. So you don't need a StringCache and they are much easier to reason about for the Polars optimizer.
This is because the type is known up front. It is not dependent on the data and doesn't change at any point in a query.
I would recommend using Enums if you have a known fixed set of categories. It allows for more parallelism and more streaming work loads.

I presume there is no copy when casting from Categorical to Enum. Is that right?

I am running into many papercuts using Enum. For example: comparing two values of enum sometimes fails with, with cryptic errors like: "failed to determine supertype of enum and u32"
E.g. of a bug: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17479#issuecomment-2213395578
Will try to be more disciplined about submitting bug/error reports from now on, given the gains with Enum, but that takes careful effort, when the actual task you're working on will be fine with a simple change to Categorical...

Right. Thanks for the bug reports. The enum is defnitely much newer than Categorical and therefore less ironed out.
